# Manually edit the html of “Thumbnail grid with expanding preview” / Delete the button of 'VISIT WEBSITE'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used this Gallery "Thumbnail grid with expanding preview" from this website:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

But I need just to know how to delete the button (VISIT WEBSITE) that appears at each time when expanding the thumbnail.

I tried several times.

Comment: Can you please put the specific code?

Comment: To help you get where that button is. head over to your file then look for `Visit website` then remove the whole anchor tag.

Comment: Or using CSS: `.og-details a:last-child{ display: none;}`

Comment: @skobaljic   Thanks a lot, it works. I think I shuold develop my skills in CSS with the aid w3schools.com .